# Get user from database using session value (Haskell - Yesod)

Tags: session, haskell, authentication, yesod

I want to get User information from database using session value instead Key.

Use this:

```
    getProfileR :: Handler Html
    getProfileR = do
    user <- runDB $ get404 $ lookupSession "_ID"
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(whamletFile "templates/profile.hamlet")
```

Instead this:

```
    getProfileR :: UserId -> Handler Html
    getProfileR uid = do
    user <- runDB $ get404 uid
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(whamletFile "templates/profile.hamlet")
```

Is it possible? Is it not recommended?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? If I remember correctly, Yesod already does those bookkeeping. It stores `AuthID` in your session which is usually the persistent key.

Comment: Can I use AuthID as Key for another tables that use UserID as foreign key? If it's possible, I believe that solves my problem.

Comment: Yes. But that's on the database schema level itself. So you can pretty much do whatever you want. Probably, we can help you better if you can say what you are trying to solve.

Comment: I want to get information related to User from database. So, I have to retrieve the logged-in UserId to find data in another tables. It doesn't need to be necessarily Session value.

Comment: You are looking for something like this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/haddock.stackage.org/lts-6.2/yesod-auth-1.4.13.2/Yesod-Auth.html#v:maybeAuth . I recommend you to go through this chapter: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization

Answer (score 0):

The type of `lookupSession` is:

```
lookupSession :: MonadHandler m => Text -> m (Maybe Text)
```

So I would try something like this:

```
    getProfileR :: Handler Html
    getProfileR = do
      uid <- lookupSession "_ID"
      user <- runDB $ get404 (Just uid)
      defaultLayout $ do
        $(whamletFile "templates/profile.hamlet")
```

Comment: I got the following error:
`/home/ubuntu/workspace/tpayesod/src/Handlers.hs:235:30:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Key t0’ with actual type ‘Maybe Text’
    In the first argument of ‘get404’, namely ‘uid’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘get404 uid’`

Comment: Well - it won't work. You've got to convert `uid` to a Text. Currently `uid` is a `Key ...`. It will work if you can convert it to a Text value somehow.